# How To use Column with Comparison operators in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, comparison

I have a table of five columns. One of the columns is "Conditions" which has comparison operators. We have them in the columns so the client can manage it. How can we build a query where these comparison operators act as operators and not as values?
Below there are three columns: Test Value , Conditions and Boundaries.
There are numeric values in Test Value and comparison operators in Conditions.  We want the Conditions to compare Test Value with Boundaries. Do I need to cast the Condition column as a string?

```
CASE 
  WHEN Test value "Condition' Boundaries Then 1 
  ELSE 0 END
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? In `SQL-Server` you have to write dynamic SQL for these kind of operations.

Comment: I'm using MySQL

Comment: MySql supports dynamic SQL using `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE` statements. You can create desired SQL query using values in column of your table. Since you haven't provided any sample data, please check [this](https://www.google.com/amp/s/blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/06/20/mysql-dynamic-sql-with-execute-and-prepare-statements/%3Famp) and try to adapt it in your use case.